# Android adb command fails

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to access my android device and pull the adb_keys file, just like in this tutorial: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/bypass-secure-usb-debugging-prompt-on-phone-with-broken-screen.2965462/#post-72808986

I cannot proceed due to the following set of errors shown below :

```
\platform-tools_r33.0.3-windows\platform-tools>adb shell
a50:/ $ ls-l
/system/bin/sh: ls-l: inaccessible or not found
```

How so I move ahead ?

Comment: Seems you never had contact with Linux/Unix, because then you would know that the command is wrong, correct is `ls -l` (with a space before `-l`). `ls` is the command and `-l` is the argument.

Comment: Thanks, man. But can you help me execute that program mentioned in the above link